# numpy array writing to an existing file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm confused as to why this isn't wanting to write to an outfile.
I extract data from a txt file using `np.loadtxt()` I try to write to an existing file, but I'm getting this error `'numpy.float64' object is not iterable'` I'm not looping through a float value, rather looping through each element of the array then writing it to an existing file.

Here's my code

```
mass = np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Luis/Desktop/data.txt',usecols=0)
with open('test','w') as outfile:
    for i in range(len(mass)):
        outfile.writelines(mass[i])
```

could it be that the function `with open()` doesn't work with NumPy arrays?
Thanks

Comment: See: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: Do us a favor, and create a simple `mass` array that produces the same error.  We can't load your `data.txt`, and thus have to guess as to its contents.

Answer (score 0):

`with open()` is a context manager used to work with files (works with all files). The `writelines()` method takes `str` as input argument. So you do have to convert to `writelines(str(mass[i]))`. But still the `temp variable i` is iterating over the line but the `max value` it takes is length of the file.(length of the file may not be equal to the length of each line in the file). I think this is what you want.

```
mass = np.loadtxt('/content/sample_data/st.txt',usecols=0)
with open('test.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in mass:
        outfile.writelines(str(line))
```